# Pop up window after the alarm signal - Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, popupwindow

I would like to know - how to show pop up window when `AlarmManager` will call? I've already created `AlarmManager` now I need to create something what will show popup window to cancel this Alarm.

My code:

```
public void setAlarm(long timeInMillis){

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        mCalendar.set(
                mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR),
                mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        );
    }

    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);
    intent.setData(currentUri);


    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);


    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

and

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);


    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

}

Comment: pop up window? you mean to say alert dialog box?

Comment: Yes, I want to create alertdialog box which will cancel calling alarm

Answer (score 0):

```
onReceive(context, intent) {
  /*show the dialog in this method. set the onclick so it can dismiss the alarm, 
    get the value for the alarm from the bundle. I may be wrong about this 
    but i think alarmManager has a cancel(PendingIntent operation) method that u can 
    just send in the intent and your done. 
    Call a stopMedia(context) method after the cancel in order to stop the media 
    that is playing
   */
   showDialog(context, intent)
   //Extract the play media code to a method for readability
   playMedia(context) 
}
```

That should solve your problem

---

Before the code was posted:

We can either use the pending intent and have an activity that handles the pending intent. or use the handler to execute the code.

In either case, create a dialog fragment and then use the appropriate context to show it. setOnClickListener { alarmManager.cancel } for the dialog fragment button.

A little more explanation may be required depending on how the alarm manager is setup

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try do it. My problem was that I needed to create AlertDialog with selected time, I mean in time which was forwarded to `AlarmManager`, because as I wrote before I want to get a „popup” Window which will be shown when Alarm will call. Do you Think your solution will be ok?

Comment: You should save the time that is sent to the alarmManager somewhere locally so the alertDialog has access to it. Without looking at the code it is hard for me to give you proper pointers.

Comment: Ok, I edited post and added fragment of my code. Let's check it

Comment: edited the response to show the code that you can probably use.

Comment: Yeah, just I'm not sure how to add it into my code, but I will try. If I succeed I will write here.

Comment: you should be able to use the snippet, define the showDialog method and create the AlertDialog there.

Comment: for showDialog I think need extends Activity, but I've already extends BroadcastReciver. Without it, I can't create showDialog. May I'm on wrong way to do it, but I'm fresh in  Android.

Comment: sorry for the confusions:
Do not use the showdialog from the activity. use the 
dialogFragment.show or AlertDialog.Builder.show()

Comment: Ahh ok ok, I've tried to use AlertDialog.Builder.show but without effect

Comment: I created AlertDialog but I get prolem: `Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: Try this, Create a new Activity class in the setWindowContents use a layout that suits your needs, show that activity and use it to stop the alarm. Perhaps that will work, I guessing that your activity is not on the screen when you are trying to show the dialog.